# How to route an IP connection from a network card adapter to a PORT in another card adapter in windows

Tags: networking, routing, ip, local-area-network

I've got an industrial PC running Windows Embedded with two network card adapters. One of the cards, let's say card1, is connected to a switch in which there are a few IP cameras connected and some others IP peripherals conforming a private net. The other card adapter, card2, is connected to the company network.
What I need to do is routing one of the IP cameras to a port in card2's IP so that it can be seen and accessed from the company network.
Is it possible in windows?

regards

[Here is a schema of what I have to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc50O.jpg)

Somehow I need to access to CAM1 from the COMPANY NET

Comment: May be you could draw a scheme?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646165/netsh-port-forwarding-from-local-port-to-local-port-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem thanks to marctxk's suggestion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646165/netsh-port-forwarding-from-local-port-to-local-port-not-working

In windows command line you just have to execute this command

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=xx listenaddress=xxx.xxx.x.xxx connectport=xx connectaddress=xxx.xxx.x.xxx

the listen port and address are the IP seen by company net and the port I want to use. The connect port and address are the IP and port of the IP camera.

You don`t have to forget to add rules to your windows firewall so that you can access the port you want to use